# Find the Shortest Distance from Point to Plane

Tags: calculus

**Sample Question**: Find the shortest distance from the point $P = \left(2,−4,6\right)$ to the plane $2x + 4y − 2z = 14$.

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Noes0nOvLg4), they are using a different method to find the shortest distance from a point to a  plane.
Summary:
$$
{D \over \left\vert\sqrt{A_{2} + B_{2} + C_{2}}\right\vert} +
\left\vert{Ax + By +Cz + D \over
\sqrt{A_{2} + B_{2} + C_{2}}}\right\vert\
\mbox{where}\ D\ \mbox{is}\ 14
$$

What's the difference between this formula and the usual distance formula to find the distance from a point to a  plane $?$ i.e.
$$
\left\vert{Ax + By +Cz + D \over
\sqrt{A_{2} + B_{2} + C_{2}}}\,\right\vert
$$

I tried both methods but got two different answers.

Comment: You should summarize the video method here. Also the usual distance formula is easy and correct, I'm not sure why you'd need an alternative method

Comment: You should describe the method/formulas they use in the YouTube video in your post. In general, it is not a good idea to force users to wander outside of the site (to something that might be deleted in the future) so they can understand your question.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I'm new to this site. I don't know that. I will summarize it. Kindly have a  look after 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

The formula in the video is **same** as the original formula that you give. It just in different kind of shape.

**Original Formula :**
$$D=\frac{\left|ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d\right|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

**Video Formula :**
$$Distance\:of\:P=\left|d\right|+\left|d_1\right|$$
$$Distance\:of\:P=\left|\frac{-d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right|+\left|\frac{D_1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right|$$
$$Distance\:of\:P=\left|\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right|+\left|\frac{ax_0+by_0+cz_0}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right|$$
$$Distance\:of\:P=\left|\frac{ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right|$$
$$Distance\:of\:P=\frac{\left|ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d\right|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

**Calculation from Original Formula :**
$$D=\frac{\left|ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d\right|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$
$$D=\frac{\left|2\left(2\right)+4\left(-4\right)-2\left(6\right)-14\right|}{\sqrt{2^2+4^2+(-2)^2}}$$
$$D=\frac{19}{\sqrt{6}}$$

**Calculation from Video Formula :**
$$\left|d\right|=\frac{\left|-\left(-14\right)\right|}{\sqrt{2^2+4^2+(-2)^2}}$$
$$\left|d\right|=\frac{14}{\sqrt{24}}$$
$$$$
$$D_1=2\left(2\right)+4\left(-4\right)-2\left(6\right)$$
$$D_1=4-16-12$$
$$D_1=-24$$
$$$$
$$d_1=\frac{\left|-24\right|}{\sqrt{2^2+4^2+\left(-2\right)^2}}$$
$$d_1=\frac{24}{\sqrt{24}}$$
$$$$
$$D=\frac{14}{\sqrt{24}}+\frac{24}{\sqrt{24}}$$
$$D=\frac{38}{\sqrt{24}}$$
$$D=\frac{2\cdot 19}{\sqrt{6\cdot 4}}$$
$$D=\frac{2\cdot 19}{2\sqrt{6}}$$
$$D=\frac{19}{\sqrt{6}}$$

Comment: Hi, But when I solve the above problem by both methods, I'm getting a different answer. By the original formula: 19/rt6 By the video formula: 14/rt6

Comment: It is impossible to get different answer since both of the formula is same.

Comment: I do edit my answer with the calculations